# Override DNS in Firefox

Tags: firefox, dns, hosts-file

I'm looking for a way to override DNS entries in Firefox, for development/testing purposes. I know the normal way to do this is via the `hosts` file, but I cannot edit it since I don't have admin access on my work machine. Does anyone know of a browser plugin/addon which would do this for me?

I did find [the SwitchHosts add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14258/), although it also requires admin rights in order to install itself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an issue on a company-owned computer. OP needs to go to their IT staff for assistance on this.

Comment: Overriding a domain name's IP resolution because of testing/development purposes is a valid reason alone, regardless of the computer being company owned or not.

Answer (score 7):

One possibility is to have a socks 5 server on a machine that you have administrative control on, set up this machine as your socks proxy in firefox, and change [`network.proxy.socks_remote_dns`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns) in `about:config` to `true`. In theory, all DNS lookups should be done through the proxy, so you should be able to supply your own IP addresses.

Comment: True that would work, although I was hoping for something a bit simpler.. Also a disadvantage to this method is that I wouldn't be able to change DNS entries on the fly.

Comment: @John, the "something a bit simpler" might be to talk to your boss to get admin privileges on your development box. This DNS issue is a very good example of why you need that, if you'd ask me!

Answer (score 6):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) has such an option: Tools->hosts

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm not able to install it on my machine either...

Answer (score 3):

If it's just for a few specific requests: the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/3829) allows for editing HTTP headers and then re-playing the request.

(For other options see also [Send Host header when accessing IP address in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857376/send-host-header-when-accessing-ip-address-in-firefox) on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

Since I ended up here looking for an answer...

According to Bug 1361099: [provide a way to map all dns to constant (probly localhost)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361099)

Firefox treats all dns resolutions as if they resolved to the IP address specified in network.dns.forceResolve when this parameter is set.

This can work for broken DNS resolution of a single host, but probably wouldn't work for a problem requiring multiple hosts to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Cant comment yet but I'd like to reference this post [Custom host file for Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/403042/custom-host-file-for-firefox)

See Plugin [FoxyProxy-Standard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177633)

Answer (score 0):

There are many plug-ins which can change the hosts file:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/change-hosts/ (not available anymore)
- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/hostadmin/ (not available anymore)
- [and more](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?q=dns)

but they all need write access to the hosts file.

I wonder, why it is not possible to edit the browsers DNS-cache.
My use-case: Seeing the local version of a page in one browser and the online version in another browser.

Comment: broken links in post