# Custom host file for Firefox

Tags: firefox, hosts

Instead of changing my host file I'd like Firefox to think my domain is on my own server while my other browser uses the real IP address. I used to edit my host files but that forces both browsers to change the IP address.

I found [change host](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-hosts/), but it doesn't appear to use the alternative host file. I also saw a comment asking when it will work on Firefox 6+.

I tried [Host Admin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hostadmin/) and it fails. It works but the alternative IP address must be in your host file already (which I don't want) and it lets you deselect a domain so the host file is ignored which is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [FoxyProxy Standard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) for that. It is free.

With FoxyProxy you can make that all requests to www.somedomain.com/* to be served by another ip address only for Firefox, without touching your hosts file, and the other browsers will be served by original/normal ip address.

It is very easy: You create a new proxy with "Add New Proxy", and in Details you assign your "other" ip address in "Host or IP Address" and the port, and later in the "URL Patterns" you enter for example "*://www.somedomain.com/*" and that is all. Only for Firefox the www.somedomain.com request will be served with the "other" ip.

Comment: It isn't clear how to configure FoxyProxy for "virtual hosting" DNS override functionality in 2019. Could this answer be expanded with images and enhanced instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the SwitchHost will help [check it out](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14258)

Comment: "Not available for Firefox 8.0"

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is [LiveHosts](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/livehosts/?src=search) plugin, it's very basic but works fine in Firefox 72.

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get it to work (FF 79). It seems to redirect from the host name to the IP address, instead of just changing the IP address "under the hood".