# Firefox is always using proxy server when entering single hostname

Tags: networking, firefox, dns, proxy, domain

We have the following problem here:

When entering a single hostname without suffix in Firefox the browser will always attempt to send this request to our proxy server. The proxy server itself is in a DMZ so it will not know what to do with that hostname.
I can also specify browser.fixup.alternate.suffix in about:config, but Firefox attempts to use the proxy anyways. The domain name (e.g. "*.corp.local") is also added to the proxy exception list, but without entering the complete FQDN (e.g. server.corp.local) manually it always uses the proxy server and fails to load the page.

Internet Explorer does the job well. When entering a single word it uses our local DNS servers and then loads the page without using our proxy. But not everybody likes to use IE.

Comment: try this addon if this helps: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchhosts/

Comment: This will not work because the users do not have administration rights on their workstations.
I can deliver some changes by a GPO, but this would mean we have a permanent change of settings.
Temporary settings are pretty tricky because a user would have to do them theirself and they might have a big lack of computer knowledge.

Comment: I know that situation. :-) so what options do we have?

Comment: how about changing the hosts file in `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`?

Comment: For 1000+ clients in the infrastructure I don't want to do changes to the hosts file, especially if there are changes to IP addresses, etc. someone needs to remember that also the hosts file needs to be updated.

Comment: There is another way if You could change an option in the `about:config` for each client. Read Dysasters answer at: http://superuser.com/questions/184643/override-dns-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your proxy to redirect unqualified requests back to a fully qualified name (as an http redirect, so the client will re-evaluate proxy rules if it should bypass the proxy).  What proxy are you using?

If it can do that, then you can do your configuration in a single place. Instead of failing at the proxy, it would succeed and bypass the firefox problem.

Alternatively you could use proxy auto config files to deal with unqualified names, this can also be centrally managed if the browsers are using default configuration.  You can find more info at http://findproxyforurl.com/

Comment: Can you explain how this service works?

Comment: I would need to know what proxy the OP is using.  But basically it would use some logic to see the request was for an unqualified name, append a domain suffix and return a redirect. [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) for example could do this with a flow-chart policy.  Disclaimer, I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.