# Override DNS in Firefox, without manipulating hosts file

Tags: firefox, dns, browser

I've got a situation where I want to be able to override the DNS for a hostname so I can access the old version of a site, and then be able to access the real version in another browser.

Add-ons like SwitchHost etc work by manipulating the hosts file, (plus most of them seem defunct). But if I do that, then the other browser will see that value too.

Either that or how do I make Firefox ignore the hosts file so I can use it make the other browser hit the old site.

Comment: Found the same question here but it's older: https://superuser.com/questions/184643/override-dns-in-firefox. Do the solutions offered there work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override DNS in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/184643/override-dns-in-firefox)

Comment: I was hoping for something easier than the socks method, the rest of the ones in there all manipulate the /etc/hosts, which won't work for my case.

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you change your hosts file?

Comment: Burgi: because if I change the hosts file then both browsers get that value. I want to be able to look at new site in one browser, old site in the other.